# Find demand function $Q_2$ assuming it is a simple quadratic function.

Tags: economics

> The demand function $Q_1 = 80 − 4P_1$ intersects another demand function $Q_2$ at $P_1 = 5$. If
> the elasticity of the second demand function at that point is one-fourth of that of the first
> one, find $Q_2$ assuming it is a simple quadratic function.

$\underline{Attempt}$

Assuming $Q_2$ is a simple quadratic function defined $Q_2=aP_1^2+bP_1+c$

Since intersection point is $(5,60)$ we have

$25a+5b+c=60$

given that elasticity of the second demand function at that point is one-fourth of that of the first so we have

$$\frac{10a+b}{60/5}=\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{-4}{60/5}$$

I have only two equation so unable to find  demand function $Q_2$. Can anyone help me to find  demand function $Q_2$ ?

Comment: Maybe the key word is $\underline{\textrm{simple}}$ quadratic function. But this is not an established term in math.

Comment: @callculus can you explain what is the  simple quadratic function?

Comment: I don't know what the mean by this term.